# Inserting into an Access table with an AutoNumber field

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I have an assignment in Java in which I need to update an MS Access Database. The database has six columns, one of them is the ID column which is an Automatic Number. I have written the update statements for five fields like this :

```
 resultSet.beforeFirst();
  if(resultSet.next()) {
    resultSet.moveToInsertRow();
    resultSet.updateString(1, FirstNameTextField.getText());
    resultSet.updateString(2, LastNameTextField.getText());
    resultSet.updateString(3, SignUpUsernameTextField.getText());
    resultSet.updateString(4, EmailTextField.getText());
    resultSet.updateString(5, SignUpPasswordField.getText());
    **Here should be the statement that updates the 6th field**;
    resultSet.insertRow();
```

Even though  it is  an Automatic Number Field i have to write something to update it or the resultSet.insert(); wont work and throw an Exception? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean MS Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested the following code against a table with an AutoNumber field named "Id" and [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) correctly inserted the new row

```java
String connStr = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr)) {
    try (Statement s = conn.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {       
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT Id, Field1, Field2 FROM ucatest");
        rs.moveToInsertRow();
        rs.updateInt("Id", 0);
        rs.updateString("Field1", "newvalue1");
        rs.updateString("Field2", "newvalue2");
        rs.insertRow();
    }
}
```

The actual value supplied to `updateInt()` is not important; the next available AutoNumber value is assigned when `insertRow()` is executed.

For more information on using UCanAccess, see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)